# equivelant tool in oracle 11g to the Oracle Enterprise manager (OEM) that came with oracle 9i?

Tags: oracle-11g, oracle9i, oem

Is there equivelant tool in oracle 11g to the Oracle Enterprise manager (OEM) that came with oracle 9i?

pointers on where to download/install/access would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download it from Oracle; [here is the product page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/grid-control/overview/index.html).